# argparse pass file only if another argument exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, argparse

How to throw error is someone gives an --inputlist but without a --update_golden?

```
gp = ap.add_argument_group(morph("Other options"))
gp.add_argument('--update_golden', action='store_true', help='It will update all golden data based on Regression ID, user can provide testlist if data to be updated for selected tests only.')
gp.add_argument('--inputlist', type=str, default=None, help='List of Input, only if --update_golden is true')
```

Is it possible to do within argparse, without an external if statement?

Comment: What's wrong with a post-parsing test?

Comment: nothing wrong, wondering if there is any without post processing